# swap a class in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to swap a class, with one other, but with a loop. When you click if the brown square he move on the blue square, and the blue square is now on the position of brown square

And many more he can move infinity. I hope you understand this problem, I post the begin of the code I have

```
var braken = document.querySelector(".board li.braken");
    var champagne = document.querySelector(".board li.champagne");

    braken.addEventListener("click", function () {
        braken.classList.remove("braken")
        braken.classList.add("champagne");
    })
    champagne.addEventListener("click", function () {
        champagne.classList.remove("champagne")
        champagne.classList.add("braken")
    })
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: how do you think a loop going to improve this code?

Comment: Hi, 
You are right with me, if I click for the first time in braken, it swap and take the place of champagne, and champagne take the place of braken, but if I click again on champagne, it does't move.

Comment: If the problem is that once you've clicked a square once and the colours have swapped that a second click doesn't change them back, that would be because the event listeners are bound to items that have the specified classes at the time the page loads. Don't use separate click handlers, just have one that has an if statement to test the current class and add/remove accordingly. (Or consider `.classList.toggle()`...)

Comment: yes, @KolaCaine - that's what your code does - what is it you want it to do instead?

Comment: heard of *this* keyword and *if conditions* ?

Comment: `el.classList.toggle()`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/classList

Answer (score 1):

using `querySelectorAll` and a `forEach` loop and `classList.toggle`

```
var things = document.querySelectorAll(".board li.champagne,.board li.braken");
[].forEach.call(things, function(thing) {
    thing.addEventListener('click', function() {
        thing.classList.toggle('champagne');
        thing.classList.toggle('braken');
    });
});
```

> Note, eventually once all browsers have caught up, or with the right polyfill - you can do

```
document.querySelectorAll(".board li.champagne,.board li.braken")
.forEach(function(thing) {
    thing.addEventListener('click', function() {
        thing.classList.toggle('champagne');
        thing.classList.toggle('braken');
    });
});
```

> "polyfill" - as long as the browser has `Array.prototype.forEach`

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = NodeList.prototype.forEach || Array.prototype.forEach;
```

Polyfill for `Array.prototype.forEach` is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` as reference to element within event handler; call `.removeEventListener()` and `.addEventListener()` to toggle event handlers reflecting `.className` change at `this` element.

```js
var braken = document.querySelector(".board li.braken");
var champagne = document.querySelector(".board li.champagne");

function b() {
  this.classList.remove("braken")
  this.classList.add("champagne");
  this.removeEventListener("click", b);
  this.addEventListener("click", c);
}

function c() {
  this.classList.remove("champagne");
  this.classList.add("braken");
  this.removeEventListener("click", c);
  this.addEventListener("click", b);
}

braken.addEventListener("click", b);
champagne.addEventListener("click", c);
```

```css
.braken {
  color: blue;
}

.champagne {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<ul class="board">
  <li class="braken">bracken</li>
  <li class="champagne">champagne</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks I misspoke,

I find the solution.

```
var braken = document.querySelector(".board li.braken");
    var champagne = document.querySelector(".board li.champagne");

    var toggle = function (li) {

        if(li.className === "champagne") {
            li.className = "braken"
        }else {
            li.className = "champagne"
        }

    }


    braken.addEventListener("click", function () {
        toggle(braken)
        toggle(champagne)
    })
    champagne.addEventListener("click", function () {
        toggle(braken)
        toggle(champagne)
    })
```